# Jquery and UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used Jquery for rounded corners (DIV) and i have a updatepanel which contains a datalist which contains som images and a delete link. When i click on delete link it fires delete command and it deletes the image.(asynchronouse postback). 
the problem is when I click the delete button my div:s has no rounded corners anymore.

Comment: :o he's listed twice. polytheism! blasphemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Register the Javascript with Sys.WebForms i believe, so that it reruns each time the postbacks happen.

eg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    YourFunction();
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(YourFunction);
});
```

You might not need to call the function first, i'm not 100% there.

Comment: I verified that you need to call YourFunction() in order to get the rounded corners to occur the first time the page is displayed. It doesn't need to be first, just called when the page is loaded.

Comment: I tried this but ran into another problem. Items outside the update panel seemed to call the function once for every time the updatepanel is updated.  Works fine within the update panel. You can see my fiddle here...[http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3DY/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3DY/3/)

Comment: Here was an alternate fiddle...[http://jsfiddle.net/5HWRX/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/5HWRX/1/)